# Python - parse_dates=True adds vertical lines to my graph

Tags: python, pandas

This is the first question I've posted here - so do let me know if I'm missing any structural etiquette or key information.

I'm having an issue when plotting data from my CSV file - it seems that when I choose to "parse dates" (using parse_dates=True within my pd.read_csv function) my graph becomes an awful lot more jumpy than it should look.

I've attached my code below showing when I do and don't parse dates - could someone point out what might be happening here and the best way to fix this?

```
sp500 = pd.read_csv("^GSPC.csv", index_col="Date", parse_dates=True)
sp500["Adj Close"].plot()
```

[image: Result when parsing dates]

```
sp500 = pd.read_csv("^GSPC.csv", index_col="Date", parse_dates=False)
sp500["Adj Close"].plot()
```

[image: Result when not parsing dates]

**Edit:** in case it's useful, the csv file is a download from the following link (I would post the csv file, though I haven't set myself up on a file hosting site yet):
[S&p 500 daily data](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/history/)

Comment: Can you post an example date? Are they ISO 8061 compliant? Do they have time information?

Comment: Hi @yorodm - there's no time information in there as it's daily data. An example of the date would be: 03/01/2000. I'll go ahead and attach my csv file to the original comment so you can see an example of the formats I'll be working with

Comment: I would advice you to use the `date_parser` keyword parameter and passs this lambda `dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: That worked - thanks very much! Is there a reason why parse_dates=True shouldn't be used in this scenario? I'm still getting myself familiar with python so apologies if that's a silly question! Might be handy to know for future reference for when to use parse_dates vs when to use date_parser

Comment: What is strange is that when I downloaded the data from yahoo finance the date format was in %Y-%m-%d format which is the default format used by `parse_dates` so I could not reproduce your error.

Comment: @Hasan no, your code was right. I just noticed that when using Firefox (default language to portuguese) the date format was not the expected, hence the parse lambda.